# Possible Market issues when increasing minSdkVersion

Tags: android

my app is currently compatible with Cupcake and up. That is: minSdkVersion is set to 3 in the manifest.

For some technical reasons I am thinking about breaking compatibility with Cupcake, by setting minSdkVersion to 4.

But I have quite a few existing users who either downloaded the lite version or purchased my app, and who are running Cupcake.

What will happen to them on the Android Market? Will they still be able to uninstall and reinstall the version which was compatible with Cupcake? Or does the market wipes old versions, so that they will be unable to reinstall in case they need to?

Any other possible problems?

I'm especially interested in feedback from developers who have already done that. In my experience, you can't really make theoretical assumptions about the Market.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They will be unable to install the old version if they ever uninstall. It should never appear in their list of apps or be found via search if you change to minSdkVersion 4.

Comment: Thanks for this info. It's pretty problematic. Has this actually happened to you? Angry users?

Comment: If you have a significant number of users, then I'd change the package name and upload it as a new version (My App 2.0 or My App HD). I'd also change the targetSdkVersion of the old version to one below the minSdkVersion of the new version, so that users only see one or the other in the market.

Comment: Well, that's quite problematic too. I would start again from the ground in regard to comments and ratings. In the case of a 2.0 version that can make sense, and I thought about this. But I'm not there yet, so now I'm more thinking about making the old version available for download from my site. It would also work for the paid version I think, while preventing piracy using the LVL, which is already integrated into my app. Thanks for the tip though. That said, I don't understand what you mean about targetSdkVersion. Right now I have it set to 8, and people running Gingerbread can see my app.

Comment: I haven't had any angry users(around 250,000k install base). A few emails asking where to find my app, but they never installed it before. Maybe the ones stuck on older devices are the ones who don't bother uninstall or wiping devices. But for the most part I've only dropped 1.5 in favor of 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Moving existing and new users to a new version might be problematic. But how about moving existing old users to a new version?

1. Fork your app and publish a "cupcake" version. Max SDK = cupcake.
2. Update your app so that if it detects that it's running on cupcake, it directs them to update to the cupcake version.
3. Update your app again with the new minSDK.

If you leave enough time between steps 2 and 3, you might get a significant number of users moved over. Even if they don't move over, they will at least be able to find your old app in the store. And you'll be able to provide whatever fixes/support for it that you want, while keeping the flagship version more up-to-date.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this, but it seems reasonable.